# How to split large mp4 video file into smaller chunks

Tags: c#, video, dll, split, mp4

I have a video file (*file.mp4, 25gb*) online over http. I would like to split it multiple playable video files of 500mb. Any directions? Could you please assist with some library?

Comment: Random thoughts for this offtopic question... One of which is why? This isn't 1999... What tech, where are you stuck?

Comment: ffmpeg -i \"exe\WeddingFullFunction.mp4\" -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:20:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 WeddingFullFunction%03d.mp4

Comment: I started using the above tool to segment the video file but it is trying to read the complete file before it starts. I wanted the buffered video segment class library in c#.